# UML - Diagrama de Classe

Tags: uml, diagrama-de-classes

Olá,

Comecei a estudar os diagramas UML recentemente e me surgiu um dúvida sobre como saber quem são os **objetos**.

Minha dúvida é, qual a melhor maneira de identificar um objeto? Pois uma classe pode ser tanto um substantivo (Cliente), quanto uma ação (Cadastrar Cliente). 
Desde já, agradeço.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve analisar não pelas classes que criará no seu programa, más pelo que as classes vão manipular, lembrando que os objetos são diferentes das classes:

- Um objeto necessita de uma classe para existir;
- Uma Classe não necessita de um objeto para existir;

Uma definição conhecida é: "Um objeto  é um termo que usamos para representar uma entidade do mundo real".

Os objetos é que devem estar no seu diagrama, pois eles terão seus atributos e serão manipulados de acordo com sua necessidade de regras de negócio.

Seguindo a linha de pensamento citado por você na pergunta, um sistema que tenha Cliente e cadastroCliente, Funcionario e cadastroFuncionario, terão como entidades o Cliente e o Funcionario, pois são eles as entidades do "mundo real".

Nesse link você encontrará mais sobre esse assunto: http://www.macoratti.net/net_uml1.htm